# Is there a way to group a block of statements?

Tags: ruby

I am working on some refactoring tool. It would be great if I can replace some method call in place by its definition, which would generally be a block of statements. For example, the original code may be:

```
some_condition ? a : b
def a
  ...
  # statements1
  ...
end
def d
  ...
  # statements2
  ...
end
```

and I want my inlining tool to replace the method call by the blocks of code directly.

To do that, I want to group a list of statements together. How do we usually do that? Is there a way of writing code like this?

```
some_condition ? {
  ...
  # statements1
  ...
} : {
  ...
  # statements2
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can use an if/else statement or extract the statements to a method.  Sometimes it also makes sense to put the statements inside a block or a Proc.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks for the advice, but I am working on some code replacement work, which would be great if I can inline some method call by a block of statements.

Comment: This is not the kind of code you want to inline. It wouldn't look that good and it would produce a syntax error. Better to use if-else here

Comment: Ternaries are basically syntactic sugar for shorter, simpler `if...else` statements. If your statement is not simple/short, that's what `if...else` statements are for.

Comment: I think a really good question is *why* do you want to do this? Speed? Using ternaries result in code that's harder and harder to read as they grow and it's very questionable that it'll result in any useful improvement. The original code is readable and is the Ruby way.

Comment: Using `if true` is not the ruby way because it always returns true. There's no need to include that part

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can either use parentheses, or `begin`...`end`.

```
true ? (
  puts "a"
  puts "b"
  puts "c"
) : (
  puts "d"
)


true ? begin
  puts "a"
  puts "b"
  puts "c"
end : begin
  puts "d"
end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You haven't voted or accepted any of the answers to your questions so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be reduced to just one line.

```
%w(a b c).each { |char| puts char }
```

The `else` statement is irrelevant here, because `true` will always return true.

Comment: Hi I updated my question description. Do you know how I can solve such a question?

Comment: Take a look at my answer